# how to open webpage in other web browser control in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have two we browsers in my form.
first form navigates to a website at load event.
now whenever user clicks any link after load of initial webpage, i want that link to be opened in another web browser control.
how can i do this??